# How to get a list of all the ASP.NET running worker process and its associated application pools?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, application-pool, w3wp.exe

I'm in a need to get a list of all the ASP.NET running worker process and its associated application pools and process ID.

Is there a way to do this pragmatically (C#) or a powershell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identify Worker Process in IIS 6.0

- Start > Run > Cmd
- Go To Windows > System32
- Run `cscript iisapp.vbs`
- You will get the list of Running
  Worker ProcessID and the Application Pool Name.

From IIS 7.0 you need you to run IIS Command Tool ( appcmd ) .

- Start > Run > Cmd
- Go To Windows > System32 > Inetsrv
- Run `appcmd list wp`

If you want to save that list to text file, just append >> myfile.txt after command.

Now, here you can see [iisapp.vbs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-PT/vscsharppt/thread/9a8de15d-4123-4c47-85e3-22525a8aa8cb) source code.

It uses WMI to get all the information. Looks simple to rewrite this to C#.

Anyway, complete article where i found this info can be seen here: [Identifying Worker Process (w3wp.exe)](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/15/identifying-worker-process-w3wp-exe-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-for-debugging-asp-net-application/)